# Is 'Rumbling' an example of an onomatopoeia?

Tags: literary-techniques, onomatopoeia

Is the word 'Rumbling' considered to be an example of onomatopoeia?
I know that the word 'rumble' is an onomatopoeia, but I am not sure if that applies to 'rumbling' as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that rumbling is an onomatopoeia hence the example of:

> "Thunder rumbling across the open sky."

I also believe it can be a case-by-case scenario. I think this because sometimes you may be describing the rumbling. This could be used like:

> "The booming rumble of thunder echoed in the valley."

You should also be aware that adding *-ing* usually does not change an onomatopoeia. For example, using the onomatopoeia crackle vs using crackling has no difference.

So, yes, I believe that rumbling is an example of an onomatopoeia.

Answer (score 0):

I was unaware of evidence that 'rumble' is an onomatopoeia but happy to take your word for it. I have less evidence than that for it but 'rumbling' would simply be what someone is doing when they rumble. The fact that *-ing* does not spoil the onomatopoeia of one's rumble is a happy accident. If you want the rumble stopped it's up to you.